# VB.NET How To Prevent Infinite Recursion During Object Population

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I'm a bit stuck right now in trying to determine the best solution to prevent an infinite recursion loop.  Perhaps it's not *exactly* "recursion", but it's a set of function calls that I can pretty much guarantee will be calling each other indefinitely if I can't come up with a solution.

In trying to figure out how to explain the issue, it seems the best way I can come up with is to start with some simplified (and redacted) code.  For this example, I'll use a Classroom and a Student.

```
Public Class Classroom
    Public Property ClassroomID As Integer
    Public Property ClassroomDescription As String
    Public Property Students As List(Of Student)

    Public Sub New(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer)
        Initialize()
        GetClassroomDetail(ClassroomID)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetClassroomDetail(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer)
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

        ' HERE'S WHERE I MAKE THE DATABASE CALL TO
        ' GET THE CLASSROOM RECORD DETAILS

        FillClassroomRecord(Reader)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillClassroomRecord(Reader)
        While Reader.Read
            ClassroomID = CType(Reader("ClassroomID"), Integer)
            ClassroomDescription = CType(Reader("ClassroomDescription"), String)

            Students = GetClassroomStudents(ClassroomID)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function GetClassroomStudents(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer) As List(Of Student)
        Dim StudentData As DataTable
        Dim ClassroomStudents As New List(Of Student)

        ' I PULL A LIST OF STUDENTS RELATED TO THE SPECIFIC CLASSROOMID

        For Each StudentRow As DataRow In StudentData.Rows
            Dim NewStudent As New Student(CType(StudentRow("studentid"), Integer))

            ClassroomStudents.Add(NewStudent)
        Next StudentRow

        Return ClassroomStudents
    End Function
End Class
```

So far, pretty straight forward.  However, the problem comes in the fact that the same student may be tied to multiple classrooms.  I want to have a similar method in the `Student` object to be able to pull all related classrooms for that student.

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property StudentID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Classrooms As List(Of Classroom)
    ...
    Private Function GetStudentClassrooms(ByVal StudentID As Integer) As List(Of Classroom)
        Dim ClassroomData As DataTable
        Dim StudentClassrooms As New List(Of Classroom)

        ' PULL A LIST OF CLASSROOMS RELATED TO THE SPECIFIC STUDENTID

        For Each ClassroomRow As DataRow In ClassroomData.Rows
            Dim NewClassroom As New Classroom(CType(ClassroomRow("classroomid"), Integer))

            StudentClassrooms.Add(NewClassroom)
        Next ClassroomRow 

        Return StudentClassrooms
    End Function
End Class
```

So, my consternation at this point is, how do I prevent it from constantly looping back and forth between the classrooms and the students populating the same things over and over again in an infinite loop?

The only thing I can think to do is to set a Boolean variable somewhere that I can set to identify whether or not to keep drilling down.  The problem is that my brain is a bit fried at the moment, and I can't figure out how to implement such a solution.

Some of the searching I've done also mentioned the possibility of some sort of "backtracking", which sounds cool, but doesn't seem very likely to work in this type of situation.  Of course, I could be wrong on that, and I'd love to see any sort of implementation that is somehow capable of intelligently identifying if I'm just looping the same things over and over again.

What I'd like to see happen is the top-level `Classroom` object creation should pick up its `Student` objects, which should pick up any additional `Classroom` objects to which they are associated, including each of those `Classroom` object's `Student` objects, and then it stops.

I hope that all makes sense.  It's actually even more complicated than this as there are other similar objects that will be tied back to the top-level object (`Classroom`), which should also follow the same basic rules - don't dig too deep into the "sub" records, and prevent an infinite recursive loop

If any clarification is necessary, please let me know.  I truly appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Why would a `ClassRoom` have any interest in the other `ClassRoom` objects?

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is "no".  Not in the sense of one `Classroom` needing to know the other `Classroom` exists *per se*.  Only as it relates to the `Student`.

Comment: Your classes are a bit overwrought.  Each Classroom doesnt need a list of Students - a List of Ids representing the students is enough.  `GetClassroomStudents`  is creating NEW STUDENTS instead of getting a list the current students from some collection of them.  If you were to iterate your list to mark some absent or set grades, it would be doing so to a different set of students than in the master/main collection.  Otherwise linq makes it easy to extract sets based on this or that property.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding.  The `GetClassroomStudents` isn't *actually* creating new students, it's just creating a new instance of the `Student` object for each of the existing `Students` in that `Classroom`.  The database is set up with a many-to-many "index" table between the two tables that contain these data elements, which I'm using to get the specific `Classroom`/`Student` pairs.  If I were to come at this using the `Student` as the "top-level", I'd want to pull all of the `Classrooms` to which the `Student` is assigned, along with any other `Students` in that `Classroom`...

Comment: Is this a multi-user application where the students and classrooms may be updated at any time, thus requiring a new call to the database for every request about the students and classrooms, or could you hold all the data client-side at runtime?

Comment: Yes, it's multi-user.

Comment: I am not confused.  `new` creates a new object.  So if "andrew" is in the VB Classroom and the C# classroom, you have created 2 distinct Andrews.  If the one on the VB class is given a Gold Star - the other same Andrew does not. With a DB in fact, if "Andrew" gets a demerit in C# it could erase his gold star depending on which gets saved first.

Comment: Ahh.  I see what you're saying.  However, I'm still not sure I understand how the solution you propose (using a list of ID's instead of the objects) will solve my dilemma.  Sorry if I'm being dense, as I said above, *my* brain is a bit befuddled at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an idea of how to solve this, but I'd like to get some feedback on my idea.

If I create an overload of the `New` constructor that accepts a boolean value (`GetRelatedDetails`), then I can call it initially with that flag set to `True`.  Just about everything else should remain the same, other than passing this value down the chain. Using the above example, it would look something like this:

```
Public Class Classroom
    Public Property ClassroomID As Integer
    Public Property ClassroomDescription As String
    Public Property Students As List(Of Student)

    Public Sub New(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer)
        Initialize()
        GetClassroomDetail(ClassroomID, False)
    End Sub

    ' OVERLOAD WITH BOOLEAN VALUE TO GET RELATED DETAILS
    Public Sub New(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        Initialize()
        GetClassroomDetail(ClassroomID, GetRelatedDetails)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetClassroomDetail(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

        ' HERE'S WHERE I MAKE THE CALL TO GET THE 
        ' CLASSROOM RECORD DETAILS FROM THE DATABASE

        FillClassroomRecord(Reader, GetRelatedDetails)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillClassroomRecord(ByVal Reader As SqlDataReader, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        While Reader.Read
            ClassroomID = CType(Reader("ClassroomID"), Integer)
            ClassroomDescription = CType(Reader("ClassroomDescription"), String)

            If GetRelatedDetails Then
                Students = GetClassroomStudents(ClassroomID)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function GetClassroomStudents(ByVal ClassroomID As Integer) As List(Of Student)
        Dim StudentData As DataTable
        Dim ClassroomStudents As New List(Of Student)

        ' I PULL A LIST OF STUDENTS RELATED TO THE SPECIFIC CLASSROOMID

        For Each StudentRow As DataRow In StudentData.Rows
            Dim NewStudent As New Student(CType(StudentRow("studentid"), Integer))

            ClassroomStudents.Add(NewStudent)
        Next StudentRow

        Return ClassroomStudents
    End Function
End Class
```

Then the `Student` object does basically the same thing:

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property StudentID As Integer
    Public Property StudentName As String
    Public Property Classrooms As List(Of Classroom)

    Public Sub New(ByVal StudentID As Integer)
        Initialize()
        GetStudentDetail(StudentID, False)
    End Sub

    ' OVERLOAD WITH BOOLEAN VALUE TO GET RELATED DETAILS
    Public Sub New(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        Initialize()
        GetStudentDetail(StudentID, GetRelatedDetails)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetStudentDetail(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

        ' HERE'S WHERE I MAKE THE CALL TO GET THE 
        ' STUDENT RECORD DETAILS FROM THE DATABASE

        FillStudentRecord(Reader, GetRelatedDetails)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillStudentRecord(ByVal Reader As SqlDataReader, ByVal GetRelatedDetails As Boolean)
        While Reader.Read
            StudentID = CType(Reader("StudentID"), Integer)
            StudentName = CType(Reader("StudentName"), String)

            If GetRelatedDetails Then
                Classrooms = GetStudentClassrooms(StudentID)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function GetStudentClassrooms(ByVal StudentID As Integer) As List(Of Classroom)
        Dim ClassroomData As DataTable
        Dim StudentClassrooms As New List(Of Classroom)

        ' PULL A LIST OF CLASSROOMS RELATED TO THE SPECIFIC STUDENTID

        For Each ClassroomRow As DataRow In ClassroomData.Rows
            Dim NewClassroom As New Classroom(CType(ClassroomRow("classroomid"), Integer))

            StudentClassrooms.Add(NewClassroom)
        Next ClassroomRow 

        Return StudentClassrooms
    End Function
End Class
```

You'll notice that, even if I pass in a value of `True` to the initial object, when it gets to the `Fill` method, and steps into the `GetClassroomStudents` or `GetStudentClassrooms`, it just calls the `New` constructor overload that defaults to `False`.  This way, I'm guessing that it should prevent it from looping infinitely back through the same records over and over again.

Of course, I'm open to any other suggestions or ideas on the best way to implement this, but I think this is what I'm going to try to do for now.